# Webhose.io and R - multiple queries from API

Tags: r, api, loops, jsonlite, webhose

Using Webhose API to pull data however each call only brings back 100 records, after which Webhose provides the next URL in the form of columns to call for the next 100 until you have all of your data. Below is what I have so far

**In my case I have 200 records which would mean I have to run it 2 times to get all the data I am looking for

```
#Pull the data from Webhose as JSON
as_json<- f"http://webhose.io/filterWebContent?token=XXXb&format=json&ts=1213456&sort=crawled&q=(China%20AND%20United%20)%20language%3Aenglish%20site_type%3Anews%20site%3Abloomberg.com")

#Convert the JSON into a DataFrame
 df_1 <- as.data.frame(as_json)

#Subset the new URL which appears as column from the first pull 
 next_url <- df_1$next.[1]

#Pull data from Webhose as JSON using the new URL - to retrieve the next 100
 as_json2 <- fromJSON(next_url)

#Convert the JSON into a DataFrame - 2nd Time
 df_2 <- as.data.frame(as_json2)
```

My problem is that need to do this iteratively until there are not any more calls to make. There is column in the data frames called moreResultsAvailable. When this hits zero it can be assumed there are no pulls left. I am assuming we would use this column to help close the loop.I also don't know how many calls this might take either.

I then want to join all the dfs together into one dataframe called combo

Anyone have any ideas as to how I can do this efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use some elbow grease and wire up the necessary boilerplate bits to iterate through the needed # of responses.

Some packages we'll need:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)
```

Creating a cpl functions will make life easier.

First, one for requesting content:

```
filter_web_content <- function(query, sort = "relevancy",
                               ts = (Sys.time() - (3 * 24 * 60 * 60)),
                               order = "asc", size = 100, from = 0,
                               token = Sys.getenv("WEBHOSE_TOKEN")) {

  params <- list(
    token = token,
    format = "json",
    q = query,
    sort = sort,
    order = order,
    size = size,
    ts = ts
  )

  httr::GET(
    url = "https://webhose.io/filterWebContent",
    query = params
  ) -> res

  httr::stop_for_status(res)

  res <- httr::content(res, as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8")
  res <- jsonlite::fromJSON(res, flatten = TRUE)

  res

}
```

Their REST API for this particular endpoint can take a few more params. If I get some spare cycles I'll whip up a pkg wrapper for this entire REST API (I'll past back here if/when I do that).

Now, one to make nice column names from potentially icky ones:

```
mcga <- function(tbl) {

  x <- colnames(tbl)
  x <- tolower(x)
  x <- gsub("[[:punct:][:space:]]+", "_", x)
  x <- gsub("_+", "_", x)
  x <- gsub("(^_|_$)", "", x)
  x <- make.unique(x, sep = "_")

  colnames(tbl) <- x

  tbl

}
```

Here's the setup bit:

- preallocate a list to avoid growing & copying. I have no idea if "30" is a good default for this API
- create a loop, increment both the list index variable and the API fetch starting position
- shove the results into the next empty slot in the list

We'll do some things with the data afterwards.

```
PRE_ALLOC_MAX <- 30
results <- vector(mode = "list", length = PRE_ALLOC_MAX)

i <- 1
from <- 0
repeat {
  res <- filter_web_content("(China AND United ) language:english site_type:news site:bloomberg.com", 
                            ts = 1213456, from = from)
  results[[i]] <- res
  if (res[["moreResultsAvailable"]] > 0) {
    message("Fetching next 100 records...")
    i <- i + 1
    from <-  from + 100  
  } else {
    break
  }
}
## Fetching next 100 records...
## Fetching next 100 records...
```

Now:

- remove any `NULL` (unpopulated) entries
- extract the part of the API result with the data we need
- wrap it up in a data frame
- make the column names great again

You don't need to do it this way, but I think it's more readable in the long run:

```
discard(results, is.null) %>% 
  map_df(~{ .x$posts}) %>% 
  tbl_df() %>% 
  mcga()
## # A tibble: 227 x 42
##                                        uuid
##                                       <chr>
##  1 ea6f6084be16a50b0d4791ffa268956ca691c16d
##  2 bd0ac60981ac73e2a7e71378881272eb5b6147d7
##  3 3f2c2c13aa2b3c6d5fc8300f3a9876d9c86c08d1
##  4 659d73d3ddba3c0a0505da8fc15862bc33ac9519
##  5 371293cf38efe9c9a4708403c816c8b33eeb1298
##  6 38a3522fe1d268519aa0e2c3c865bbee19f9ee65
##  7 a4b1f0e4a8d94354ae41c80bebe56237b5a39ca8
##  8 323660c1c21662a1e5b147455f7a4c70f60e12b8
##  9 3233102dbbed6bd90c19ddb2cf7df9111de6ffcf
## 10 c4f126943968be899a6c5fdd806274f0ca848714
## # ... with 217 more rows, and 41 more variables: url <chr>, ord_in_thread <int>,
## #   author <chr>, published <chr>, title <chr>, text <chr>, highlighttext <chr>,
## #   highlighttitle <chr>, language <chr>, external_links <list>, rating <lgl>,
## #   crawled <chr>, thread_uuid <chr>, thread_url <chr>, thread_site_full <chr>,
## #   thread_site <chr>, thread_site_section <chr>, thread_site_categories <list>,
## #   thread_section_title <chr>, thread_title <chr>, thread_title_full <chr>,
## #   thread_published <chr>, thread_replies_count <int>,
## #   thread_participants_count <int>, thread_site_type <chr>, thread_country <chr>,
## #   thread_spam_score <dbl>, thread_main_image <chr>,
## #   thread_performance_score <int>, thread_domain_rank <int>,
## #   thread_social_facebook_likes <int>, thread_social_facebook_comments <int>,
## #   thread_social_facebook_shares <int>, thread_social_gplus_shares <int>,
## #   thread_social_pinterest_shares <int>, thread_social_linkedin_shares <int>,
## #   thread_social_stumbledupon_shares <int>, thread_social_vk_shares <int>,
## #   entities_persons <list>, entities_organizations <list>,
## #   entities_locations <list>
```

Consider poking around the rOpenSci github source for API packages. A few of them have similar idioms for doing this type of API iterative thing.

**UPDATE**

You can now use the 2 functions in https://github.com/hrbrmstr/webhose for this. You'll need to do this to install it until it's on CRAN:

```
devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/webhose")
```

If you want to handle pagination on your own or just query for a single set of results, then do

```
res <- webhose::filter_web_content("(China AND United) language:english site_type:news site:bloomberg.com", ts = 1213456)
```

If you want automatic-API pagination then:

```
res <- webhose::fetchall_web_content("(China AND United) language:english site_type:news site:bloomberg.com", ts = 1213456)
```

I'll be a while before I cover the rest of the API.